# Sidekiq mailer can't find table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I'm trying to use Sidekiq with Ruby on Rails to perform some updates in the background. But I've met a strange problem

When I pass an object id to the worker, I get a '**Can't find a table Tasks**' error

Here's my code, for example:

```
class PygmentsWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(task_id)
    task = Task.find(task_id)
    task.update_attribute(:body, "well...")
  end
end
```

I call worker after the save.

```
@task = Task.new(task_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @task.save
    PygmentsWorker.perform_at(1.minute.from_now, @task.id)
```

Comment: did you restart your sidekiq & your server? Maybe even restart redis. That's what I'd start with

Comment: @TheChamp yeah. Several times

Comment: Hmm ok, and in your console this works fine? And what is the param that gets passed? Is it the integer?

Comment: @TheChamp yeah, I pass an ID

Comment: Just to be sure, you can call `Task.find(id)` from your console? 'cause maybe a migration didn't work or sth

Comment: although you perform sth similar in your code, so I guess it's fine...

Comment: @TheChamp yeah. When I call that from the console or directly from the controller, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Sidekiq task, some task information will be stored at redis storage(with default), remember that redis can not store ruby instance, so if you create a task with object instance params, all will be convert to string and object disappeard.

So if you want to call some object instance, better pass string or number and then create or find object in worker again.

Comment: Once I met this problem, and saw the error data in sidekiq idle with all worker params turn into string and when task called, error happend. If you adhere to pass object, [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Marshal.html) may usable I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid. I accidentaly started Sidekiq in the production envoronment while rails were started in the development.

Comment: No probs, glad it's solved now. Can be really frustrating sometimes not knowing what the problem is :)